# Biblatex not finding citations

Tags: biblatex, zotero, better-bibtex

I have been going out of my mind trying to fix this problem. I recently moved from `natbib` to `biblatex`, as a lot of my references contain unicode characters. My citations used to work find using `natbib`, but since I have moved across to `biblatex`, they are not being found, resulting in the following:

[image]

Below is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}


%Citations
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Sed ut perspiciatis \parencite{wilk1968}.

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file (`test.bib`), which is located in the same directory as the `.tex` file is shown below:

```
@article{wilk1968,
  langid = {english},
  title = {Probability {{Plotting Methods}} for the {{Analysis}} of {{Data}}},
  volume = {55},
  issn = {00063444},
  url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334448?origin=crossref},
  doi = {10.2307/2334448},
  abstract = {This paper describes and discusses graphical techniques, based on the primitive empirical cumulative distribution function and on quantile (Q-Q) plots, percent (P-P) plots and hybrids of these, which are useful in assessing a one-dimensional sample, either from original data or resulting from analysis. Areas of application include: the comparison of samples; the comparison of distributions; the presentation of results on sensitivities of statistical methods; the analysis of collections of contrasts and of collections of sample variances; the assessment of multivariate contrasts;\_ and the structuring of analysis of variance mean squares. Many of the objectives and techniques are illustrated by examples.},
  number = {1},
  journaltitle = {Biometrika},
  urldate = {2018-06-01},
  date = {1968-03},
  pages = {1},
  author = {Wilk, M. B. and Gnanadesikan, R.},
  file = {}
}
```

My `.bib` file was exported using Better BibLaTeX from Zotero. Any help is greatfully received.

Comment: Did you run biber?

Comment: If you use `biblatex` you need to run Biber and not BibTeX (as you did for `natbib`). A full compilation run should be LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for more background info.

Comment: Not related to the issue at hand (because the MWE compiles just fine): `babel` should be loaded with a language option (which can also be given as global option to `\documentclass`). I seem to remember that in older versions of `babel` there was an error if no language was given, but that does not seem to be the case any more. Still, you should tell `babel` which language you want (that is important for `csquotes` and `biblatex` as well). The combination of `citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=authoryear` is unusual and citations may be hard to find in the bibliography.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems the issue was the setup of TexStudio as mentioned above. Thanks for the additional comments @moewe, they are very useful.